# What is the difference between peer to peer and client/server connections?

Tags: p2p

I would like to know what is the difference between peer to peer and client/server connections for example i have 2 online games but one uses peer to peer and the other connects the client to the server and then retrieve the coords(example) to another player connected. if both type of connections have the same result what is the difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model will provide more details for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, client/server implies a request/response idiom: client makes a request, server sends response.  There's no response from server to client without a triggering request.

[Peer-to-peer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) means the communication is two-way: requests and responses can flow in both directions.

Comment: It means that each peer in the network can send a request to any other.

Comment: Why is that not safe?

Comment: Yes.  It implies that everyone on the network has been verified and is trusted.  You have to authenticate to join the network and be designated as a peer.  Why not safe?